# Syling child elements

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have style for Button

```html
<Style x:Key="menu_button" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Label Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

it must be applied to the buttons

```html
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Создать тест" Style="{DynamicResource menu_button}"/>
    <Button Content="Тесты" Style="{DynamicResource menu_button}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

How to make that do not prescribe style to each button, and enter it in the StackPanel. After all, it will be very tiring

Answer (score 2):

In case you can move the style and you do not use the style at another place you can do it this way:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Label Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Button Content="Создать тест"/>
    <Button Content="Тесты"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Yes it work, but I need that this style was applyed only for some element who have target button.
I am referring to the principle of CSS DIV > a{color: red;}